# Drop databases on a server conditionally from a List 

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have created a list of databases I want to drop based on a set of conditions and have titled it `delete_table` in the master database (this already excludes master, tempdb, model and msdb). The only column in this table is `name` which contain the exact database names that should be deleted.

How would I go about writing the script that would drop the databases on the server based on this list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick way

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL+ 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM delete_table
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

a bit safer way to make sure database exists and each database get scripted only once incase you have dups

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL+ 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM delete_table); 
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

**Edit** to add alter database simply add this line

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL+ 
'ALTER DATABASE '+ QUOTENAME(name) + 'SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;' +
'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM delete_table); 
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks! this works quite nicely. One last thing, is there a way to do the: ALTER DATABASE [database_name] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE command easily for all the databases?

Comment: I have added the "alter database set single user..."

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick way to script out `DROP DATABASE` commands:

```
--set database in single user mode, rolling back active transactions...be careful!
SELECT 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;' FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN (...)
UNION
--drop database
SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN (...);
```

Replace `...` with a comma separated list of database names (e.g `N'DatabaseOne', 'DatabaseTwo'`, etc.). Run the select query, then use results for execution.

I don't understand the need for a user table to solve this. As a side note, you should avoid creating user objects in `master` database. Granted, I can't think of a reason other than one based on aesthetics, but it just seems *wrong*.

**More on user-created objects in system databases...**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx) states user objects shouldn't be created in `master`, but I think the reason provided is pretty weak. A more substantive argument involves lack of control over what happens to system database objects during service pack/version upgrades.

I'm not saying the next service pack upgrade will wipe out your user created objects in `master`, but who knows. Put your utility and administration-type objects in a user created database so there's no confusion.

Comment: Agree on not creating user object in master.

Comment: What if I were to delete the tables I created after the script was completed?

Comment: I don't see why the table of database names is needed. Why not put your conditions directly in the query provided above? Tell us what your conditions are for dropping a database, and we can incorporate into the solution.

Comment: The way I have it working now is I create a table containing the date when the database was created and when it was last accessed.  The condition I have set is that the currentdate - createdate/lastaccessdate > 30.  The databases that meet this condition are listed down in the delete_table table. I'm fairly new to SQL and this is the only way I knew to go about doing this

Comment: OK, how are you determining the last access date?

Comment: WITH agg AS
(
   SELECT
       max(last_user_seek) last_user_seek,
       max(last_user_scan) last_user_scan,
       max(last_user_lookup) last_user_lookup,
       max(last_user_update) last_user_update,
       sd.name dbname
   FROM
       sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, master..sysdatabases sd
   WHERE
     database_id = sd.dbid  group by sd.name
)
SELECT
   dbname,
   last_read = MAX(last_read),
   last_accessed = MAX(last_accessed)
   INTO temp_table2

Comment: FROM
(
   SELECT dbname, last_user_seek, NULL FROM agg
   UNION ALL
   SELECT dbname, last_user_scan, NULL FROM agg
   UNION ALL
   SELECT dbname, last_user_lookup, NULL FROM agg
   UNION ALL
   SELECT dbname, NULL, last_user_update FROM agg

) AS x (dbname, last_read, last_accessed)
GROUP BY dbname
HAVING dbname NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
ORDER BY 2;

Comment: I'm worried that the `last accessed` in the script above doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: In your query `last accessed` has to do with **index** read/update operations...this does not mean this is the last time the **database** was accessed.